# Mounting a S3 bucket using s3fs utility AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, s3fs

I am using `s3fs` utility to mount a S3 bucket on an EC2 instance.

After crossing so much hurdles I am able to mount the S3 bucket.

I have few queries :

1. If I mount a S3 bucket on EC2 instance do I need to make any entry to the `fstab`.
2. If I mount a S3 bucket on EC2 instance then the I can see the files and folders in the mount device like /s3mnt but I am not able to see the contents on the S3 bucket. Does the content disappears from the bucket??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically mount the S3 bucket when the server boots by adding an entry to /etc/fstab using the following syntax:

```
s3fs#bucket-name /s3mnt fuse allow_other,_netdev,nosuid,nodev,url=https://s3.amazonaws.com 0 0
```