# AWS S3 bucket mount script not work on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, fuse, s3fs

I'm working on Amazon AWS and want to mount S3 bucket "mybucket" on AWS ec2 instance. Then I can easily write/read files and it will be linked together.

I was following this tutorial:: https://www.emfluence.com/blog/amazon-web-services-integrating-s3-and-ec2-few-simple-steps

However, when I reboot the instance it got stuck and I can't connect to ssh. I thought this problem was with /etc/fstab entry which I have made:

s3fs#mybucket /mnt fuse defaults,uid=33,gid=33,allow_other,use_cache=/data,default_acl=public-read,use_cache=/tmp/s3-cache,passwd_file=/var/www/mysite/security/mybucket 0 0

then I found this issue resolution::
[Mounting a S3 bucket using s3fs utility AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729520/mounting-a-s3-bucket-using-s3fs-utility-aws)
and update my /etc/fstab entry::

s3fs#mybucket /mnt fuse allow_other,_netdev,nosuid,nodev,url=https://s3.amazonaws.com 0 0

now issue starts:: whenever I reboot my instance then my mount location "/mnt" not respond and shows this error::

-bash: cd: uploads: Transport endpoint is not connected

Then I first umount it with `sudo umount /mnt` then run `sudo mount -afv` and it starts working

Please guide me how can set this /etc/fstab entry? So I can mount mybucket automatically on every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this entry on `/etc/fstab`:

s3fs#mybucket /mnt fuse allow_other 0 0 -use_cache /tmp/cache

And make sure you don't have any other mount name `/mnt` that came from the EC2 instance configuration.

Comment: same output:: 
-bash: cd: /mnt: Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: might be this issue is with credentials. but not sure. please guide if you know it

Comment: Try look at the suggested solutions here: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/105

Comment: all of these have already been done. difference b/t my problem and these issues is endpoint disconnected on reboot. when i run "sudo mount -afv" it works

Comment: I have the same problem.  Regardless of how I reconfigure it, it fails to reconnect on reboot...